# Pass a variable from one Class to another in PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to pass a string variable from `Main_Window` class to another `QDialog` class in PyQt. I can't understand what I do wrong. I want to pass `host_mac` variable from Main Class to QDialog Class. Here the main part of my code.

Here is the QDialog class:

```
class Client(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Client, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pb = QPushButton()
        self.pb.setObjectName("connect")
        self.pb.setText("Connect") 

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pb)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(self.pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.set_client)
        self.setWindowTitle("Learning")

    def set_client(self):
        self.client = self.le.text()
        print 'provided client mac is ' + self.client + 'and host_mac is ' + Main_window_ex.host_mac
```

And here the Main_Window Class:

```
class Main_window_ex(QMainWindow, Ui_Main_window):   
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
    """
    Default Constructor. It can receive a top window as parent. 
    """
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)


    self.host_mac = 'blah blah'

#more code beneeth
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Main_window_ex' has no attribute 'host_mac'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Main_window_ex.host_mac` refers to a *class* variable (as `Main_window_ex` is only a class), but you are wanting to access the *instance* variable. In other words, `host_mac` is not defined until the class is instantiated.

There are a few ways around this. Assuming `Main_window_ex` is responsible for creating `Client`, then one simple way is to pass the variable to `Client`:

```
class Client(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, host_mac, parent=None):
        self.host_mac = host_mac
        ...
```

And use it like:

```
    def set_client(self):
        self.client = self.le.text()
        print 'provided client mac is ' + self.client + 'and host_mac is ' + self.host_mac
```

As a side note you may want to use the new style connection syntax:

```
# old style
# self.connect(self.pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.set_client)

# new style
self.pb.clicked.connect(self.set_client)
```

Comment: please fill the way I pass the `host_mac` in my `Client` class --> `self.w = Client(self.host_mac)` just to clarify to others how the problem is setled! Thank you for your answer!